# Build java project with different jdk version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build, compilation

I'm encountering an issue with my Maven build process. My system has JDK 17 installed, and I also have JDK 19 in a different directory, `C:\sdks\jdk-19` I need to build a specific project using JDK 19, but there's a constraint: I can't temporarily change the JAVA_HOME environment variable to JDK 19 because it's also required by SonarQube.

Here are the details:

- JDK 17 is currently set as the default in my system.
- I have set the project's Java version to 19 in the pom.xml file.

When I run `./mvnw clean package`, I encounter the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project Myhanie: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 19 -> [Help 1]
```

My goal is to build this project with JDK 19 without changing the `JAVA_HOME` variable temporarily. Is there a way to configure Maven to use JDK 19 for this specific project, considering the constraint I mentioned?
I've already checked that JDK 19 is correctly located in 'C:\sdks\jdk-19,' and this is my `pom.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mihanie</groupId>
    <artifactId>Myhanie</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Myhanie.Sb</name>
    <description>Myhanie.Sb</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.project-lombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: See the second answer in the linked duplicate target.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca
 I have already try this solution, but another error occur ```[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project Myhanie: Compilation failure -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project Myhanie: C ompilation failure```

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and include the modifications you made to your pom and the *complete* error, because what you showed in your comment is a bit too vague.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca
I find out the error, thank you for your time, but I have another question about java version, because i use 1.9 in pom.xml, I thought it's java 19. What is the difference between Java versions that use a dot (e.g., 1.8, 1.9) and versions that don't (e.g., 17, 18)?

Comment: It's just a different (old) way of naming java versions. 1.8 is Java 8, 1.9 is probably Java 9 but I've never seen it numbered that way, always as "Java 9".

Comment: oooh I get it, thank you man.